# Scheduled task not working in AWS EC2 using CRON, Whenever gem

Tags: cron, ruby-on-rails-5, whenever

I'm following an article on backup up a database using http://backup.github.io/backup/v4/

My `schedule.rb` looks like this:

```
every 1.day, :at => '2:00 am' do
  command "backup perform -t staging_backup"
end
```

and I run the whenever task using:

```
execute :bundle, :exec, "whenever --update-crontab"
```

When I checked the crontab list `crontab -l` it gives me

```
 # Begin Whenever generated tasks for: /home/deploy/apps/calltree_staging/releases/20180221015812/config/schedule.rb at: 2018-02-21 01:58:56 +0000
     0 2 * * * /bin/bash -l -c 'backup perform -t staging_backup'    
 # End Whenever generated tasks for: /home/deploy/apps/calltree_staging/releases/20180221015812/config/schedule.rb at: 2018-02-21 01:58:56 +0000
```

but the scheduling is not working, but when I try to run manually

`backup perform -t staging_backup`

it immediately performs the backup

Comment: maybe it is unable to find the path for backup, redirect the output to a log file to see if it's throwing out any errors.

Comment: also, you need to add absolute paths in the cron to minimize the errors.